# make auto-choice in terminal

Tags: terminal, steam

I would like to know if there is a way to make a choice in terminal using command line.

For example: when I type `sudo update-alternatives --config glx` 
I get the response:

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative glx (providing /usr/lib/glx).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia          100       auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/fglrx           99        manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/fglrx/igpu      90        manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/mesa-diverted   5         manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/nvidia          100       manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I would like to make a command where I can execute a lot of stuff in the same line without having to type this choice. Something like

```
sudo service lightdm stop && update-alternatives --config glx && ??? && service lightdm start
```

I'm glad if someone could help me with this.